# Image not scaling in container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

I am trying to resolve an issue where I have followed multiple tutorials on how to make an image within a container responsive. I have done everything I feel I can but for some reason the image still doesnt fill the box.

I have also tried importing the image with CSS and using the background: cover; property.

How can I make this image FILL the left column, and for the text to remain on the right hand side?

```css
#about .container {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px -10px rgba(59, 66, 71, 1);
  border: 0.5px solid #72A7A3;
}

.about-photo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container col-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5 about-photo">
          <img src="img/avatar.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-7 about-text">
          <h1>Hi, I'm <span class="text-primary">Oliver Stott</span></h1>
          <p>thisi s a test </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `w-100` class to `img` if you want image fit into parent element.

```
<section id="about">
 <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="container col-6">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5 about-photo">       <img src="img/avatar.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100"> 
          </div> 
         <div class="col-7 about-text"> 
            <h1>Hi, I'm 
           <span class="text-primary">Oliver Stott</span>
           </h1> 
         <p>this is a test </p>
 </div> 
</div> 
</div>
 </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sice you already know the height of container,

try this

1) if you dont want to stretching the image while resizing,

```css
#about .container {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px -10px rgba(59, 66, 71, 1);
  border: 0.5px solid #72A7A3;
}

.about-photo .img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #eee url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/66997/pexels-photo-66997.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="about">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container col-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5 about-photo">
          <!-- <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/66997/pexels-photo-66997.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="img-fluid"> -->
          <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-7 about-text">
          <h1>Hi, I'm <span class="text-primary">Oliver Stott</span></h1>
          <p>thisi s a test </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

2) if stretching is fine, do this :
change

```
.about-photo img {

 height: 100%; // from auto to 100%
}
```

and add

```
#about .container .row{
 height: 100%
}
```

```css
#about .container {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px -10px rgba(59, 66, 71, 1);
  border: 0.5px solid #72A7A3;
}

.about-photo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#about .container .row{
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="about">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container col-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5 about-photo">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/66997/pexels-photo-66997.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-7 about-text">
          <h1>Hi, I'm <span class="text-primary">Oliver Stott</span></h1>
          <p>thisi s a test </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This works, but it is no longer responsive, as the height of the image stays at 300px.

Comment: your container is fixed height , so what you mean by responsive? container height is not going to change since you put height:300px

Comment: did you mean like this [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/jayakrishnancn/6m5bpydc/)

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
.about-photo 
{ background-image : url(img/avatar.jpg); 
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: hello, yes i have tried this :( it still doesn't fill.

Comment: I'm surprised, my website is all about displaying images (it's a graphic design website) and this works 100%, I would suggest going through your css to see if there is another css property overriding it.